# APM server configuration in docker compose with elasticsearch and kibana

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, apm

I'm trying to install the Elastic APM with Elasticsearch, Kibana and the APM server as 3 services with docker-compose. The file should look like this:

```
version: "2.2"

services:

  setup:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
  
  es01:
    depends_on:
      setup:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - ${ES_PORT}:9200
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
     #xpack security
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://localhost:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  apm-server:
    image: docker.elastic.co/apm/apm-server:8.0.0
    cap_add: ["CHOWN", "DAC_OVERRIDE", "SETGID", "SETUID"]
    cap_drop: ["ALL"]
    ports:
      - 8200:8200
    command: >
      apm-server -e
        -E apm-server.rum.enabled=true
        -E setup.kibana.host=kibana:5601
        -E setup.template.settings.index.number_of_replicas=0
        -E apm-server.kibana.enabled=true
        -E apm-server.kibana.host=172.29.143.107:5601
        -E apm-server.kibana.username=elastic
        -E apm-server.kibana.password=elastic
        -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["172.29.143.107:9200"] # ["es01:9200"] results the same
        -E output.elasticsearch.username=elastic
        -E output.elasticsearch.password=elastic
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      retries: 12
      test: curl --write-out 'HTTP %{http_code}' --fail --silent --output /dev/null http://localhost:8200/

volumes:
  certs:
    driver: local
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  kibanadata:
    driver: local
```

Docker container starts but **apm-server test output** fails when running inside APM container.

[image]

Elasticsearch and kibana are ruuning fine.

Comment: kibana config is removed due to code limitations. ES and KB are up and running fine

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/apm-server-config-in-docker-compose-with-es-and-kibana/301227

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar scenario recently and my solution was:

1 change the host in apm-server.yml to `["https://elasticsearch:9200"]` (only worked with https)

1.1 (if in docker-compose your elasticsearch container name is es01, you can use `["https://es01:9200"]`)

2 in your apm-server.yml set SSL verification to none **(only for development purposes)**

```
output.elasticsearch.ssl.verification_mode: none
```

or

```
output.elasticsearch:
 ssl.verification_mode: none
```

Restart your APM Server and then it probably will work

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

If SSL verification is not disabled, *it will connect*, but you will see:

[image]

Hope it helps